# Why is AVQueuePlayer able to initiate audio stream from url in background while AVPlayer cannot?

Tags: ios, background-process, avplayer, ibeacon, avqueueplayer

I've been testing background audio on ios triggered by location updates (iBeacons). I noticed that if I want to initiate an audio stream when my app is backgrounded it only works if I am using and instance of AVQueuePlayer. If the file is local I can use AVPlayer to play a single instance of an audio file, but not if it is streaming from a url.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?